# Resetting CSS properties in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reset, bookmarklet

I'm trying to attach new `<div>` element with some content via bookmarklet and add some inline CSS.

The problem is that the CSS from the main page usually affects this div too.

What would be preferred approach to ensure that my styles from bookmarklet are always more important that the ones from any parent page?

The most trustworthy solution would be to set all possible CSS properties for each element inside the div. Is this wise? Where can I get the list?

I've found [cleanstate.css](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate/blob/master/cleanslate.css) which may do the reset.

Maybe some js solution would work better? Eg. detect which styles has been aplied by the main page, and reset them to default values? I'll have jQuery available in this bookmarklet anyways.

Comment: do you mean using !important at the end of your style properties: e.g `background-color: green !important`;

Comment: !important for my styles is not enough, I'd need to use !important on all of the styles, not only the few ones I'm setting. I'd like the new div to behave like a separate page.

Comment: Maybe including the `<link...` style file after the parent style link. This will insure that all of your child divs overwrite the parent divs. e.g `<link rel="stylesheet" href="parentStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="childStyle.css">`.

Answer (score 1):

The reliable solution would be iframe.

You can create it dynamically and assign content using 'javascript:' protocol in src tag.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src = "javascript:'<div> Yours Content </div>'";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Or you can insert empty iframe, wait it to be loaded and modify iframe document as required. For example:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src = 'about:blank';
document.body.appendChild( iframe  );

iframe.onload = function() {
  iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = '<div> Yours content </div>';
};
```

Alternatively, you can create separate .html page and insert it as iframe. `<iframe src="http://example.com">`Although, you will need to host page somewhere and document won't be able to access parent page without additional scripting. ( `.postMessage()` )